# Logging out on django web app redirects to django admin logout page. What's going on?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm following a tutorial in the Python Crash Course book on creating a simple web page using Django. I've just created an app to log a user in and out on my page, using Django's default user authentication system. When I logout, Django is not redirecting to the template I've created to show that the user is logged out. Instead it redirects to the Django admin logout page.

Here is my base urls.py file.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),

]
```

Here is my 'users' app urls.py file.

```
from django.urls import path, include

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    # Include default auth URLs
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Here is my base.html template.

```
<p>
<a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Hello, {{ user.username }}.
    <a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">Log out</a>
  {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">Log in</a>
  {% endif %}
</p>
```

Here is my logout.html template.

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>You have been logged out. Thanks for stopping by!</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Here are my installed apps in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My Apps
    'learning_logs',
    'users',

    # Default Apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

When the page redirects to the Django Admin logout, the url shows up as http://localhost:8000/users/logout/ which is the url I want. Also, I am using my admin username and password to login to the web page.

Any help is appreciated!

edit: Django version being used is 3.2.6. Version being used in the tutorial is 2.2

Answer (score 4):

in settings.py you can sett [logout redirect url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url)
Give this a try

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/path_to_the_page'
LOGIN_URL = '/path_to_the_page'
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the right direction. How should I write the URL? I tried /users/logout which is the web page I'm trying to get to but the page doesnt redirect properly. How do I get Django to see the logout.html template I am trying to use?

Comment: so you have a custom view with template logout.html right? then you have to add the URL of that custom logout view in the logout_redirect_url, I guess you got the point..

Comment: I get the first part, but i'm having trouble with the url. LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'users:logout' redirects to http://localhost:8000/users/logout/ which is the correct url, but throws the browser error the page isn't redirecting properly. If I redirect to the url LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'users:login' which points to a template in the same directory it works just fine. It's literally just 'users:logout' which isn't working. What am I missing?

Comment: Okey, share the logout view its URLs, and the full error you got.

Comment: There actually aren't any views for this app. I am not sure why because I'm so new, maybe because it is using the default django authentication system which has is own default views? Anyway, the other url 'users:login' also does not have a view, and works okay. The browser error I get is: The page isn’t redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. Server in console just shows [31/Aug/2021 23:40:44] "GET /users/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 etc. repeated.

Comment: when you click on  localhost:8000/users/logout which page is showing? is that the default Django auth page?

Comment: It is just a blank firefox page with the message "The page isn’t redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236636/discussion-between-sumithran-and-badelf).

Comment: I fixed it. It turns out the logout template MUST be named logged_out to work with django's default authentication. When I changed it, and deleted the LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL setting, it worked. Jiminy Christmas :D Thanks for the discussion though, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! It turns out the logout template MUST be named logged_out.html to work in this context. When I renamed it from logout.html the page redirected properly to the custom logout template.

Answer (score 1):

**Just change the templates HTML file name with logged_out.html**

> Here is my logout.html template.

```
> Here is my logged_out.html template.
```

Answer (score 0):

in your settings you can do that easily how suppose you have function based view

```
def hello(request):
    return render (request, 'logout_redirect.html')
and in url
  path('hello/', views.hello, name="hello")
```

so in your settings do this

```
LOGIN_URL = 'accounts:login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'accounts:home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'accounts:home'
```

and second way just pass in your views

```
@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('accounts:login')
```

both the type is neccessary to be in your page first is for if a user logout from admin panel tell where to go  and second for a custom user to tell where he have to redirect so you can change your logout redirect url different for both diffrent type of user or if you want to redirect on same url for both of the user pass the same path

and i do recommend you to read the full documentation of django for better iunderstanding
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/